# Why won't my slide toggle work?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, nav

I have a nab bar and I want one of the items in the nav bar to open up a drop down menu when clicked. I have this:

```
$("#dropdown_menuitem").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

However the drop down menu never appears on click, my html looks like this:

```
<li id="dropdown_menuitem"><a href="#">MyAxon<img style="padding-left:5px;" src="img/drop-down.png"/></a>
    <ul class="dropdown reverse_gradient">
         <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
         <li class="lastElementInDropDown dropdown"><a href="#">Students</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
.
.
```

Edit:
I tried `alert($(this).find('ul').html());` and I got an alert with the both the `<li>` elements.

`$(this).find('ul').show(200);` didn't work either

The content is not dynamically added.

My css looks like this:

```
 nav.main_nav ul.dropdown{
     opacity: 0; 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 35px; 
     left: 10px;  
     border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 
     -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
     -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
     display: none;
     z-index: 100;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Its working fine for me, can you post a fiddle with your code denoting the problem?

Comment: Works fine, which means there is more to this ([see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cFec/)). Is that menu item added dynamically? Are you sure the click event is called?

Comment: Following from what Chad said - if the content is added dynamically, you'll need to use `.live()` to bind the to the `click` event.

Comment: Looks like the click event gets called, because I added an alert.

Comment: @KarlBarker in the newest versions of jQuery `.live` is deprecated he would use `.on`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem, I had set opacity to zero in my stylesheet, which was preventing me from seeing the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you have to make sure that what you click on isn't the link itself. Here you do a .click even to the li - But what if the user actually clicks the link? Well then they will be redirected to the href within the link.

So in order to prevent that you have to add a click event to the link it self:

```
$("#dropdown_menuitem a").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).parent().find('ul').length > 0) {
         e.preventDefault():;
    }
});
```

This will check if a dropdown exists in the current li - If it does we won't have it redirect the user to interrupt our JavaScript execution. So what we does is to prevent the current event. Such as the redirect.

Try it out and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Still not working with this. clearly I have problems somewhere else

Comment: Do you get any error output? If not try to use the console.log(); method to throw out text to the browser. Then make a few of these and see if the click event is even triggered. You could also try to use chrome or firebug in firefox to spot if the element is changing. For an example you ccould open the html viewer. Find the ul and then click the li. Then see if anything happens to it. If something does try hover over the element to see if it's a problem with z-index or position of the element.